# Data in column instead of row

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to display the modules in a program, along side the program as one row, instead of having multiple rows of modules for each program.

```
    SELECT program.program_title as program, course_module.title as unit
    FROM program_module
    INNER JOIN program
        ON program_module.program_id = program.id
    INNER JOIN course_module 
        ON program_module.course_module_id = course_module.id
```

Generates:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23413810/Stack/current.png

How can I get it to appear as this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23413810/Stack/desired.png

Comment: What database are you using? Do you want the data in separate columns or in one column with comma separated string like Programming,Networking,...?

Comment: Oracle EDIT: Sorry I ready that as date, separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.program_title, 
listagg(m.module_title,',') within group (order by m.module_id) as module_title
from program_module pm
inner join program p on pm.program_id = p.program_id
inner join module m on pm.module_id = m.module_id
group by p.program_title
```

sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3652/5

Answer (score 2):

If you want separate columns, rather than a single comma-separated column, you could use a pivot. From 11g there is a built in pivot command; or you can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
SELECT program,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 1 THEN unit END) AS unit1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 2 THEN unit END) AS unit2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 3 THEN unit END) AS unit3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 4 THEN unit END) AS unit4
FROM (
  SELECT program.id as program_id,
      program.program_title as program,
      course_module.title as unit,
      row_number() over (partition by program.id
          order by course_module.title) as pos
    FROM program_module
    INNER JOIN program
        ON program_module.program_id = program.id
    INNER JOIN course_module 
        ON program_module.course_module_id = course_module.id
)
group by program_id, program
order by program;
```

Either way you need to know how many modules are possible, and have handling for them all (adding more case statements with this version).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/acfce/4).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
SELECT program.program_title as program, LISTAGG(course_module.title, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY course_module.title) as unit
FROM program_module
INNER JOIN program
    ON program_module.program_id = program.id
INNER JOIN course_module 
    ON program_module.course_module_id = course_module.id
GROUP BY program.program_title
```